# What is the difference between sudo pip3 install pygame and sudo apt install python3-pygame

Tags: python, pygame

At first I entered the command `sudo pip3 install pygame` in order to install pygame but then when I entered `sudo apt install python3-pygame`, It did not prompt me saying that it was already installed. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`apt` is for Debian packages. `pip` is for Python packages.

`python3-pygame` is Python's `pygame` repackaged as a Debian package. So, technically, not the same as the Python package.

So the difference is how `apt` and `pip` report an already installed package.

Comment: There's more to it than that - the apt one will bring in any C libraries it depends on and should be properly matched to the system version of those libraries.  You won't get that dependency matching with pip and might end up needing to also download and build one or more C libraries for some packages manually.

Comment: True. I wanted to keep it ELI5.

Answer (score 1):

They may not get you the same version.

`pip` will get the latest from the pypi package index.

`apt` will bring you the version that was included for your ubuntu/debian release.

`pip` can also be used in a virtualenv so as not to pollute your system packages.

In general the `pip` version will be the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

apt is for linux. pip is for python